# Symfony routing through custom bundle only works in console mode

Tags: php, routes, symfony

I am new to Symfony but not to PHP. I just can't figure out why I can't get a homepage route to work from a custom bundle, but it does appear to be working from console output. When I execute the route in my web browser it will always retunr the `/` route from the AppBundle, i.e. the default Symfony welcome page even though the AppBundle has been removed from the `registerBundles()` function in AppKernal.php. I can confirm this because if delete the AppBundle directory from /src I will get the following error log:

```
[2016-06-22 19:07:57] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"homepage"},"request_uri":"http://bvd-v3.dev/"} []
[2016-06-22 19:07:57] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-06-22 19:07:57] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController" does not exist." at /Users/apple/projects/mentel/bvd-v3/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2498 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Class \"AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController\" does not exist. at /Users/apple/projects/mentel/bvd-v3/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2498)"} []
```

Yet, if I call `php bin/console router:match /`

The output is:

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | homepage                                                |
| Path         | /                                                       |
| Path Regex   | #^/$#s                                                  |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     | 
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: MentelBundle:Index:index                   |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I call `php bin/console debug:router`

The output is:

```
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_info             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}            
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  _twig_error_test           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  homepage                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /
```

---

Contents of routing.yml:

```
mentel:
    resource: "@MentelBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Contents of routing_dev.yml:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Contents of `registerBundles()` in /app/AppKernal.php:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new BVD\MentelBundle\MentelBundle(),
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

Contents of controller:

```
<?php

namespace BVD\MentelBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('?');
        return $this->render('@mentel/pages/home.html.twig', array(
            // ...
        ));
     }

 }
```

Thanks for reading my question, would really appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: so i think there is and misunderstood. @Route("/", name="homepage")  means hostname.de/  ist the route if u want hostname.de/ homepage @Route("/homepage", name="homepage") you should use

Comment: I don't want that `/homepage` I want a route served from the domain, i.e. `http://example.com` which would be a `/` but what you say doesn't matter, because changing the route to `/something_else` would just give a Symfony 404. Since there is no AppBundle route for that.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache (`bin/console cache:clear`)?

Comment: @Oldskool - yeah, I did try that too. The output seems to show it clears without any issue: `[OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.`

Comment: @Oldskool - Aha you were mostly totally right. I was running `bin/console cache:clear` but it was clearing the dev cache only and the application was running in prod mode evidently... which I hadn't realized. Running `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` solved the issue for me. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```